# Error message "cannot find symbol"

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am quite new to java and programming. I´m using the textbook "Java how to program". I am solving an excercise (3.11 p. 136). In this excercise i am trying to get an application with two classes to print out  information about a gradebook. It is supposed to print out two strings for each of the two objects of the class, with the information: "gradeBook1 course name is:CS101 Introduction to Java Programming, instructor is Donald Duck". Some other informations for gradebook 2. I am supposed to use get and set-methods, and to use a constructor. I have worked quite a lot now without managing to compile the "gradeBookTest class" which contains the main method. I get the following error message:

```
aGradeBookTest.java:8: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable gradebook1
location: class aGradeBookTest
    System.out.printf( "gradeBook1 course name is: emphasized text%s,\n instructor is %s\n", gradeBook1.getCourseName(), gradebook1.getInstructorName() );
                                                                                                          ^
aGradeBookTest.java:9: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getInstructorname()
location: class aGradeBook
    System.out.printf( "gradebook2 course name is: %s\n, instructor name is: ", gradeBook2.getCourseName(), gradeBook2.getInstructorname() );**
```

The code for the two classes are the following:

```
public class aGradeBook
{
    private String courseName;
    private String instructorName;

    public aGradeBook( String name, String iName )
    {
        courseName = name;
        instructorName = iName;
    }

    public void setCourseName( String name )
    {
        courseName = name;
    }

    public String getCourseName()
    {
        return courseName;
    }

    public void setInstructorName(String iName)
    {
        iName = instructorName;
    }

    public String getInstructorName()
    {
        return instructorName;
    }

    public void displayMessage()
    {
        System.out.printf ("Welcome to the gradebook for\n%s!\n", getCourseName() );
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class aGradeBookTest
{
    public static void main( String[]args )
    {
        aGradeBook gradeBook1 = new aGradeBook( "CS101 Introduction to Java Programming", "Donald Duck" );
        aGradeBook gradeBook2 = new aGradeBook( "CS102 Data structures in Java", "Tom & Jerry" );

        System.out.printf( "gradeBook1 course name is: %s,\n instructor is %s\n", gradeBook1.getCourseName(), gradebook1.getInstructorName() );
        System.out.printf( "gradebook2 course name is: %s\n, instructor name is: ", gradeBook2.getCourseName(), gradeBook2.getInstructorname() );
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me, I am stuck here?

Comment: `String[]args` should be: `String[] args`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote `gradebook1` in your code instead of `gradeBook1`.

The `gradebook1` variable does not exist and that is what the compiler is telling you: `cannot find symbol symbol : variable gradebook1`.

Answer (score 3):

Also for the instructor name:

```
public void setInstructorName(String iName)
    {
    iName = instructorName;
    }
```

You probably mean:

```
public void setInstructorName(String iName)
    {
    instructorName = iName ; // I swapped the variables 
    }
```

And in your `main` method, you should call:

```
 System.out.printf( "gradebook2 course name is: %s\n, instructor name is: ", gradeBook2.getCourseName(), gradeBook2.getInstructorName() // Change is from getInstructorname() to getInstructorName()
```

Using an IDE such as Eclipse, Netbeans or IntellijIDEA would help you spotting those errors

Answer (score 0):

you have mistmatching cases for both the method name getInstructorname() (should be getInstructorName() ) and gradebook1 (gradeBook1).